# Bug in rep graph in activity page of profile?

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, reputation-graph

The bottom of the reputation card on the activity page is all squished together:

[image]

The "next privilege" seems to be overlapping with the rep graph or something...is this on purpose? Has it always been and I just haven't visited my profile in forever? Or is it a bug?

I'm on Chrome on a Mac booting Windows. The track a tag badge is looking good for me on Sci-Fi and Fantasy (where the above pic is) but on Quantum Computing where I'm a mod there's no button to switch back to the rep-next-privilege dealio, which I guess is because there's no more privileges for me to get as mod? (But what about rep milestones?)